# Обьясните, почему не работает seekg и seekp

Tags: c++, fstream

Ранее эти функции не требовались. Файл открывался для чтения, данные записывались в вектор, потом запись удалялась в векторе и файл перезаписывался.

Теперь файл открыт для чтения, записи и дозаписи. И для проведения алгоритма описанного выше нужно пользоваться функциями `seekg`, `seekp`, чтобы устанавливать курсор в нужную позицию. Вот метод, что не так ?

```
void DBTextFileAdapter::remove(string login)
{
    file->seekg(ios_base::beg);
    while (*file >> user._login >> user._password)
    {
        container.push_back(user);
    }
    for (vector<User>::iterator it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->_login == login) //находим запись
        {
            container.erase(it); //удаляем запись
            break;
        }
    }
    file->seekp(ios_base::beg); //это не работает
    for (vector<User>::iterator i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i)
    {
        *file << i->_login << " " << i->_password << endl; //перезапись
    }
    container.clear(); 
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что раньше вы не переустанавливали текущую позицию файла на начало, а он сам переустанавливался туда? Выглядит как-то странно.

Comment: ранее я читал файл с помощью ifstream, закрывал. Потом открывал с помощью ofstream и закрывал, позиции были постоянно с начала файла. И методы seek..() не требовались. Теперь же обьект fstream как я обьяснил и эти методы по идее необходимо использовать.

Comment: Что такое "это не работает"? В чем оно выражается?

Comment: @Spaceman: Окей, это важно. Добавьте это в вопрос. (Ну и объясните, в чём выражается «не работает», да.)

Comment: Только все равно размер файла потом придется править (truncate или какая у Вас ось?). Так что, первоначальное решение (с переоткрытием для записи) было лучше (KISS-принцип).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, вызов

```
file->seekp(ios_base::beg);
```

формально не легален. У этой функции есть две версии

```
basic_ostream& seekp( pos_type pos );
basic_ostream& seekp( off_type off, std::ios_base::seekdir dir);
```

`ios_base::beg` - это значение типа `ios_base::seekdir`, которое может быть только вторым параметром второй версии метода. Вы же суете его в первый параметр, тем самым вызывая первую версию метода, но подсовывая ему значение `ios_base::beg` в качестве абсолютной позиции. Оно оказывается конвертируемым к типу `pos_type`, т.е. код компилируется, но чему именно оно получается равно в результате - кто его знает...

Такая же проблема имеет место и с

```
file->seekg(ios_base::beg);
```

Правильно

```
file->seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
...
file->seekp(0, ios_base::beg);
```

или просто

```
file->seekg(0);
...
file->seekp(0);
```

Во-вторых, цикл чтения закончился с потоком в состоянии `fail()` (выставились `failbit` и `eofbit`). Пока состояние `fail()` не сброшено, т.е. пока поток не переведен в состояние `good()`, он будет игнорировать все операции ввода-вывода. Сделайте

```
file->clear();
```

перед тем, как переходить к записи и только после этого уже `seekp` и т.д.

Comment: это все прекрасно, но перезапись не осуществляется с вашими правками.

Comment: @Spaceman: Добавил "во-вторых" в ответ.